# Undefined reference to C++

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I have a class Settings declared like this (in Settings.h file) - just part of it:

```
class Settings {

public:
  Settings(const edm::ParameterSet& iConfig);
  ~Settings(){}

}
```

Then I want to use it in another class called TMTrackAnalyzer. In TMTrackAnalyzer.h I have this:

```
#include Settings.h

class TMTrackAnalyzer : public edm::EDProducer {

 public:
  explicit TMTrackAnalyzer(const edm::ParameterSet&);
  ~TMTrackAnalyzer(){}

 private:
 Settings *settings_;
}
```

and in TMTrackAnalyzer I have this:

```
TMTrackAnalyzer::TMTrackAnalyzer(const edm::ParameterSet& iConfig)
{
    settings_ = new Settings(iConfig);
}
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
undefined reference to `Settings::Settings(edm::ParameterSet const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I understand this error appears mainly when you don't call the function properly (with the same parameters that you define it with), but I can't find the reason why I get this error. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You do have the `Settings` constructor *defined* (implemented) in a source file you build (link) with?

Comment: You need to define and link to`Settings(const edm::ParameterSet& iConfig)`.

Comment: @NathanOliver but I think I do this (I am not sure tho). I call multiple classes, not just Settings, and all the other work fine.

Comment: @Bobo Where do you have `Settings(const edm::ParameterSet& iConfig) { some code here }`?

Comment: They are not in the same folder as TMTrackAnalyzer. But actually when I include them I use:  #include <TMTrackTrigger/TMTrackFinder/interface/Settings.h>

Comment: Settings.h you shown us does not include a definition of the **constructor**, only one for the destructor.

Comment: @manni66 The constructor is defined in Settings.cc which I didn't put here.

Comment: Then you don't compile/link Settings.cc or there is a bug in it.